# Setup RD gateway on a single ec2 instance VPC

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, rdp

I have an AWS environment where

- for each client, there is a dedicated ec2 windows instance.
- There is NO active directory; each ec2 instance is like in its own workgroup.
- Each instance is deployed on its own dedicated VPC, security group etc.
- Clients use RDP to connect from their site to the ec2 instances whenever required over port 3389.

The clients' ip addresses are known upfront and we open port 3389 to allow RDP connection.

**Now we want to introduce the RDP using SSL (port 443)**

The typical guides from Amazon and other books walk thru setting up a RD Gateway in a SEPARATE ec2 instance and use that as the jump box.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/rd-gateway/architecture.html#best-practices

This is all good except that,

- I do not want to have an additional ec2 within each VPC.
  (*I understand that there are other options to have a centralized RD Gateway in its own vpc and then using VPC peering etc. But I don't want to go that route for various reasons*).

**So, my question is**:

> Is it possible to setup the RD gateway directly on the ec2 instance to
>   which I ultimately want to RDP into ?  and use SSL(port 443) for
>   connecting thru RDP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer : No. RD gateway is a custom EC2 appliances. It is common sense : nobody can maintain an appliance that run other services that may disrupt the appliance core services.

Comment: Thanks mootmoot for your time and answer. Probably my questions was not clear enough. I was able to achieve what I wanted and have posted the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

- I tried this out successfully. I created an EC2 windows 2016 server.
- I installed RD gateway using the powershell command.

  Install-WindowsFeature RDS-Gateway -IncludeManagementTools
- Then I launched the RD gateway manager.
- configured the CAP and RAP to allow my Remote Desktop Users to access any resource.
- Used the ssl certificate which I created using certroot in linux.
- From aws console, opened the port 443 in the security group to allow connections from my public to the ec2 instance. (No other ports were opened).
- From my local computer, I setup a RDP connection such that:

  The RD Gateway server setting had the RD gateway server name (ex. poc.mydomain.com)
  This should match the ssl certificate.

  The remote computer name was specified as "localhost" (implying that the same server needs to be connected to).

  After providing the right credentials, I was connected the the ec2 instance using RDP.
  [image]

[image]